# Cannot create Chrome controlled person - add person screen hangs forever

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome

I tried to enable password protected accounts in Chrome on 16.04.

When I add a regular person in Chrome, it takes 1s or less.

However, when I try to create a controlled user, the add user screen hangs forever. It's been trying to create a user for the past 30min and it's still trying.

[image]

My machine is strong - i7, 16GB RAM, SSD,...

Anyone had issues like this and who did you solve them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. It's either a bug or intentional feature, but in any case, I did not get any warning so it's got to be a bug.

Anyhow, it happened that I had 2 users' screens open i.e. Person 1 had open screens, as well as Person 2. So when I tried to create Person 3 supervised account, I got the but I mentioned in the post.

I fixed it by closing 1 person thus leaving only 1 person's screens activated. I was able to create supervised user in a matter of seconds.